СДЭК API: Как передать роль отправителя в поле 'Кем я являюсь' для корректного отображения?
Я использвую СДЭК API для интеграции впшного сайта c кабинетом сдэка. При передачи данных в накладной в поле "Кем я являюсь" автоматически отображается "третьей стороной", вместо "отправителем". В доке апишки сдэка не нашла указание через какое поле передается данный параметр. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне передать корректно роль отправителя?
